# Преобразование даты в SQL запрсе

Tags: android, sql, kotlin

в приложении на kotlin для android есть дата в формате дд.мм.гггг (текст полученный из поля ввода), как ее преобразовать в гггг.мм.дд в SQL запросе вида 
`"SELECT ФИО FROM users WHERE ФИО = '${fio!!.text}' AND дата between тут дата and тут дата ORDER BY DESC"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Вариант Java:**

Используйте `SimpleDateFormat`, например:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
Date date = format.parse("12.01.1998");

SimpleDateFormat format2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String date2 = format2.format(date);
```

`date 2` - отформатированная строка для SQL-запроса

**Вариант MySQL:**

```
SELECT ФИО FROM users 
    WHERE ФИО = '${fio!!.text}' AND дата 
        BETWEEN 
            STR_TO_DATE('ТУТ_ВАША_ДАТА в фомате dd.mm.yyyy', "%d.%m.%Y") AND 
            STR_TO_DATE('ТУТ_ВАША_ДАТА', "%d.%m.%Y") 
ORDER BY дата DESC
```

**Вариант SQLITE:**

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858275/alternative-to-str-to-date-in-sqlite

Comment: способа проще нет? типа DATE_FORMAT(дата, '%d.%m.%Y') для использования внутри запроса?

Comment: @Ксения попробуйте STR_TO_DATE, обновил ответ

Comment: в SQLite нет функции `STR_TO_DATE`, раз вопрос об Android

Comment: @Eugene Krivenja на стаке есть оба тега «sql» и «sqlite», в теме явно указан первый

Comment: В SQL как таковом тоже нет этой функции, она есть только в MySQL